# Apparent sudden increase in Outlook 2010 Mapi sessions

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Platform - Windows 7, Outlook 2010, Exchange 2010, Lync 2013 add-on.

A few weeks ago we started testing IE11 in a pilot, in the last few days we have noticed a significant increase in the following errors on the Mailbox server especially with these pilot users:

- MSExchangeIS, event ID 9646, "Mapi session {GUID} {fqn} exceeeded the maximum of 250 objection of type "objMessage "

This article explains how to increase these configuration limits:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477612.aspx

Our users see an error when this occurs - 'too many simultaneous windows are open', even if they only have one outlook window open.  The easiest way for them to resolve this is to restart Outlook, sometimes it can be reset using the Reconnect button in the "Connection Status" Outlook tray icon.

We are concerned that this is masking another issue, is there a way to monitor and identify the MAPI sessions to ensure they are being managed properly.  Better still, has anyone else seen this & if so how did you resolve it?

Thanks,

Comment: If you downgrade form IE11 to something lower does the IMAP connection count go (back) down?

Comment: Hi thanks, only users that have been upgraded have seen this so far.  We haven't tried removing IE11 from an affected machine.

Comment: Was the only change made to the machines the upgrade from a previous IE to v11?  Before upgrading to IE11 did these machines work as expected?

Comment: I have clarified the problem based on feedback from my team.  The install of IE11 (from IE8) required some pre-requisites:

KB2533623
KB2639308
KB2670838
KB2729094-v2
KB2731771
KB2786081
KB2834140-v2
KB2882822
KB2888049

& the following post install:

KB2963952
KB2976627

The issues has only been seen with this frequency in the last few days (perhaps 3-4 times a week), on any machine.  It has occurred but much less frequently in the past